# django and d3.tsv, not working

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js

I am totally confused now, it just does not work!

my django views:

```
def data_tsv(request):
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('epk'))
    occurrences = event.occurrences.all()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/tsv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="data.tsv"'

    for occ in occurrences:
        response.write('%s  %s\n' % (occ.timestamp, occ.counter))

    return response
```

my js:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,

g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.close);
    });

d3.tsv("{% url 'data_tsv' %}?epk={{ event.id }}", function (d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
    return d;
}, function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.close;
    }));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .select(".domain")
        .remove();

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Price ($)");

    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);
 });
```

and I am getting

[image]

my data.tsv looks like this:

```
2017-02-12 14:07:14.566084  1
2017-02-12 14:07:35.718406  1
2017-02-12 17:12:14.380712  1
2017-02-12 17:23:40.195434  1
2017-02-12 17:51:52.866287  1
```

I am trying to get this code to running: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

any help is highly appreciated

**EDIT**: after changing how Mark said: I am getting now

[image]

the two log lines are coming from:

```
console.log(d.date);
console.log(parseTime(d.date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `tsv` file has headers of `date` and `close` and that the file download from django is working, then your problem is date parsing.

This line:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
```

is a date like "02-Feb-17", but you have "2017-02-12 17:51:52.866287", which is close to:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L");
```

**But** this gets a little trickier since JavaScript dates only have *millisecond* precision, you'll have to knock off the microseconds:

```
d3.tsv("someData.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date.substring(0, d.date.length-3)); //<-- parse correctly
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  ...
```

Running code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tS58pvB96f6eYa9bn8EQ?p=preview).

Comment: weird, after I change the date to "2017-02-12" format and `d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")` I am still getting the error.

Comment: I logged the date after being parsed, I see this `Sun Feb 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)` and before parsing it looks: `2017-02-12`

Comment: I updated my question with new error message :confused:

Comment: @doniyor, use my plunker link above, fork that, reproduce your error there and I'll take a look.  I'm a little lost, seems like you are changing the date format `django` is producing and how it is parsed with `d3` but not showing me how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: got it I will fork your plunker and give you the link

Comment: damn, on plunker it works http://plnkr.co/edit/Moyyawptt8lY0pLBDQDr?p=preview I am now stuck. what can be wrong?

Comment: I can download the tsv file from my django backend, it works

Comment: d3 error messages are horrible. I dont know where to debug now

Comment: @doniyor, is your server public-facing?  I'm not sure how to help any further :(  The error message is not from `d3` but the browser itself.  It means `d3` is doing math on something not a number and producing `NaN`s.